# How to use .format to format a string

Tags: python, string, format

I am trying to format the following select statement:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint({x}, {y}, {z}),4326) FROM " + config['PostgreDB']['table_name'] + ";".format(x, y, z))
```

when i run the code i recived the below posted error message

please let me know how to format this select statement correctly

**code**:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint({x}, {y}, {z}),4326) FROM " + config['PostgreDB']['table_name'] + ";".format(x, y, z))
```

**error**

```
FEHLER:  Syntaxfehler bei »{«
LINE 1: SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint({x}, {y}, {z}),4326) FROM slo...
```

Comment: `cursor.execute("SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint({x}, {y}, {z}),4326) FROM {table};".format(x=x, y=y, z=z, table=config['PostgreDB']['table_name']))
`?

Comment: You should probably use your database’s *parameterized query API* to begin with instead of manual string interpolation prone to SQL injection.

Comment: Instead of using formatted text, you can pass tuple of values.

Comment: @ThePyGuy would you please provide an example

Comment: Use .format  before concatenation like : cursor.execute("SELECT. ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint({x}, {y}, {z}),4326) FROM ".format(x, y, z) + config['PostgreDB']['table_name'] + ";")

Answer (score 0):

Use .format at the end of first string...

Use it like this:-

```
cursor.execute("SELECT. ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint({x}, {y}, {z}),4326) FROM ".format(x=x, y=y, z=z) + config['PostgreDB']['table_name'] + ";")
```

Alternatively you can use f-strings if your python version is above or equal to 3.6

Code:-

```
cursor.execute(f"SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint({x}, {y}, {z}),4326) FROM " + config['PostgreDB']['table_name'] + ";")
```

Comment: `format(x, y, z)`  will give error in your case. You will need to do `format(x=x, y=y, z=z)`